# What's the difference between new int and new int() vis-a-vis compiler?

Tags: c++, initialization

There are two ways to get the integer pointer

```
int *i = new int;
int *i = new int();
```

I know the later option will set the integer to 0. But how are they different to compiler. Is new an operator and new(), overload of operator?

Comment: Nope, they dont, try printing both values

Comment: @UKMonkey: Read the answer mentioned above.